# Promise resolved data is not accesable

Tags: typescript, ionic3, es6-promise, angular-promise

First of all would like to explain what I am trying to achieve. I fetch restaurants from the database, after that I add calculated distance from user position and restaurant position. Where I add this as property to the restaurant object. Then I would like to sort my results based on that distance from nearby to far away.

But the promise result(restaurant with distance) does not contain the distance.

Here is my code how I have tried, the console logs returns me the array WITH distance but when I set an breakpoint in the chrome debugger I am not able to see that property.

This is the promise `calculateDistance function`:

```
 calculateDistance(restaurants: Array<Restaurant>): Promise<Array<Restaurant>> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        // const restaurantDistances = [];

        restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
            const restaurantLocation: LatLng = new LatLng({
                lat: restaurant['Restaurant']['Lat'],
                lng: restaurant['Restaurant']['Long']
            });

            this.locationService.getUserLocation().then(() => {
                this.googlemapService.initGoogleMapsApi().then(() => {
                    const distance = this.googlemapService.computeDistanceBetween(this.locationService.location, restaurantLocation);
                    restaurant['Restaurant']['Distance'] = distance;
                    // restaurantDistances.push(restaurant);
                    console.log(restaurants, 'restMap', restaurant, distance);
                    resolve(restaurants);
                });
            }).catch( error => {
                console.log('error = ', error);
            });
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

this is inside the success function:

```
this.calculateDistance(restaurants).then((restaurantsDist) => {
  console.log('after Calc distance', restaurantsDist, restaurants);
  this.determinInstanceStorage(fetchMethodName, restaurantsDist, resolve);
});
```

Can Somebody help me out, I resolve the result in a `map` method maybe this is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think the main issue that you're running into is that you're calling `resolve(restaurants)` inside the `restaurants.map` loop. This means that on the first iteration of the loop, you're going to resolve the promise. Now if you're loop is small enough and the processing time is small enough for each of the iterations, you might not really notice it as the loop will continue and things will get populated, but any "point in time" investigation (such as breakpoints) will reveal what you're seeing -- that not all the restaurants have been processed.

There are a couple of other things that I think might help, too. Not being familiar with the APIs you're using there or the environment you're working in, I can't be 100% sure. With both `this.locationService.getUserLocation` and `this.googleMmapService.initGoogleMapsApi` they look like operations that only need to happen once (not for each instance of the `restaurants` loop). Can you pull those out of the `restaurants.map` loop?

Also, changing this to an `async` function may make it easier to read since you have that multiple cascade of `then`s. So, in the end, something like this:

```
async function calculateDistance(restaurants: Array<Restaurant>): Promise<Array<Restaurant>> {
    await this.locationService.getUserLocation();
    await this.googlemapService.initGoogleMapsApi();
    restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
        const restaurantLocation: LatLng = new LatLng({
            lat: restaurant['Restaurant']['Lat'],
            lng: restaurant['Restaurant']['Long']
        });

        const distance = this.googlemapService.computeDistanceBetween(
            this.locationService.location, restaurantLocation
        );
        restaurant['Restaurant']['Distance'] = distance;
        // restaurantDistances.push(restaurant);
        console.log(restaurants, 'restMap', restaurant, distance);
    });
    return restaurants;
}
```

This is written "off-the-cuff" so can't say it will function as-is, but should give an idea.

Comment: Excellent. Let me know if helps.